# Get the specific data cell in the table when button is clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I was wondering how to get the specific data cell if the button is clicked inside my the HTML table. I used jquery on it but only the first row was alert.

**This is my Html.**

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css"  rel="stylesheet">


    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <script src= "https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" ></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src = "address.js"></script>




  </head>
  <body>
    <p><br/><br/></p>
    <div class = "container">
            <table id="table" class = "table table-bordered table-striped table-hover">
                <thead> 
                    <tr>
                  <th>State</th>
                  <th>Street Address</th>
                   <th>Street Name</th>
                  <th>Copy</th>

                    </tr>

                </thead>

            </table>
    </div>



  </body>
</html>
```

**This is my .js**

```
$.getJSON("MOCK_DATA.json", function(data){

  var items = [];

  $.each(data, function(key, val){
    items.push("<tr>");
    items.push("<td  id=''"+key+"''>"+val.state+"</td>");
    items.push("<td id=''"+key+"''>"+val.street_add+"</td>");
    items.push("<td id=''"+key+"''>"+val.street_name+"</td>");
    items.push("<td>"+'<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="copy">Copy</button>'+"</td>");



        items.push("</tr>");


 });

  $("<tbody/>", {html: items.join("")}).appendTo("table");




});


 $(document).on("click", "#copy", function() {
       alert("Copied " + $("td" ).html());
});
```

**The data of the table is on json**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach to accomplish that:

1) use [data-attributes](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_global_data.asp) at the button tag with your desired value;

2) remove id from the button and add a semantic class do the button to allow event binding later (you can have only one unique id per document).

3) bind event directly to the button and get value reading the correspondent data-attr.

Something like that:

```
...
items.push("<td>"+'<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-copy" data-value="' + val.street_name + '">Copy</button>'+"</td>");
...
$(document).on("click", ".btn-copy", function() {
       var value = $(this).attr('data-value');
       alert("Copied " + value);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

There are few issues in your code

1: it is trying to assign same id to different td elements, which will make your html invalid.

2: you are delegating the event based on a an id selector which will definitely work for a single element.

You should try with changing the choice of selectors, if you are targeting multiple items then you can use class selector.

Check the example below, it giving the  each copy button different id attribute but same class attribute.

Attach the event with this class Copy and using this you can get the other elements of the same row.

```js
var data = [{
  state: "A",
  street_add: "A",
  street_name: "A"
}, {
  state: "B",
  street_add: "B",
  street_name: "B"
}]

var items = [];

$.each(data, function(key, val) {
  items.push("<tr>");
  items.push("<td  class='state_" + key + "'>" + val.state + "</td>");
  items.push("<td class='street_add_" + key + "'>" + val.street_add + "</td>");
  items.push("<td class='street_name_" + key + "'>" + val.street_name + "</td>");
  items.push("<td>" + '<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary copy" id="copy' + key + '">Copy</button>' + "</td>");

  items.push("</tr>");


});

$("<tbody/>", {
  html: items.join("")
}).appendTo("table");



$("#table").on("click", ".copy", function() {
  console.log("Copied ", $(this).parent().siblings());
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

  <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <head>
    <body>
      <p>
        <br/>
        <br/>
      </p>
      <div class="container">
        <table id="table" class="table table-bordered table-striped table-hover">
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th>State</th>
              <th>Street Address</th>
              <th>Street Name</th>
              <th>Copy</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
        </table>
      </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use closest to get the near tr to your button in the table :

```
var tr =$(this).closest("tr")
```

Then get all the td data you need